# How to scroll a fluent UI modal to the top everytime it renders using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, spfx

In an SPFX (SPO) webpart I have 2 buttons which change pages on a Modal form.
Everytime the next page renders I want it to scroll to the top.
I'm attempting to assign an id to the MS Fluent UI modal but can't. If I could do this then I'm sure I could use `element.scrollTo()` etc.
Here's the modal:

```
<Modal
            
 titleAriaId={this._titleId}
 subtitleAriaId={this._subtitleId}
 isOpen={this.state.showModal}
 onDismiss={this._closeModal}
 closeButtonAriaLabel={"Close"}
 isBlocking={true}
 containerClassName={this.state.ReduceSize}
 id={'modal') //it doesn't accept this!
 >

<div id={'top'} ... />
```

I'm also trying to use an id tag of 'top' for each page and attempting to use something like this whenever a Next page button is clicked:

```
  var el = document.getElementById('top');
      console.log(el); //This gets the correct id and displays the className details. But how can I scroll to it?
      
el.scrollTo() //or whatever should work because this doesn't.
```

I've read the docs for https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html and
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/modal#IModal in the latter I've particularly paid attention to the `componentRef` property which could hold the answer but am clueless on how to use as there is no example.
Need some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

I had a footer component which had 2 buttons on it. Next and Prev. I was using a handler function to pass the functions for the buttons up to the Parent, I stuck this into the handler:

```
  var el = document.getElementById('top');
      console.log(el);
      el.scrollIntoView();
```

And also applied `id={'top'}` to the header of the modal. Everytime I change page now, it scolls to the top!